# NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing google calendar API into my custom app. What I want to do is add event into Google Calendar.

But I got this error when comes to call this line:

```
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
```

Error:

```
    java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found
```

I've search for solution for few days but still can't find a way to solve this, now I completely have no idea how is this error come out. Any help will appreciate.

Comment: I also have the exact same issue. From what I've researched, it has to do with Java KeyStore not being compatible with android, so you have to convert it to BouncyCastle KeyStore instead. Still looking for a solution at the moment.